# Is referencing the /etc/bashrc in your ~/.bashrc file mandatory or needed?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to add custom aliases and set up some environment variables in a `~/.bashrc` file. My question is do I need to reference the system wide /etc/ file to make sure I get all the other set-up done in that file? I have seen this code in some sample `.bashrc` files that I have found while trying to figure this out:

```
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc   # --> Read /etc/bashrc, if present.
fi
```

I am even less than a mere mortal when it comes to Unix!

Comment: Your `/etc/bashrc` (or `/etc/bash.bashrc` on some distros) will set the system-wide configuration for all users. Any specific settings will go in your `~/.bashrc`. On login, your `/etc/profile` will automatically cause your `~/.bashrc` to be read. Also, any `PATH` additions go in your `~/.profile` not `~/.bashrc` (otherwise you will append another set of paths each time an *interactive* shell is started.)

Comment: ~/.bashrc is sourced by ~/.profile, not /etc/profile (at least on my system)

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not needed. In fact, it is likely to pollute your own idea of what your environment should look like.

**You** are the one to specify the aliases, variables and functions you need, not some random distro creator or sysadmin dude. Look at the contents of `/etc/bashrc`, take the 10% you like and forget about the other 90% useless bloat.

Answer (score 1):

The `sourc`ing  of `/etc/bashrc`

```
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc   # --> Read /etc/bashrc, if present.
fi
```

is a sensible way  to avoid conflicts with:

1. environment variables
2. aliases

So not referencing `/etc/bashrc` is not a good idea.

**Note:** When a new user is created a **skeletal** `.bashrc` is usually copied from `/etc/skel` to the home folder for the newly added user. If not you could manually copy it. It is a good place to get started.

Comment: What if `/etc/profile` already sources `~/.bashrc`. You need to advise the OP to check.